# JSでsetTimeoutでのスライドショーの停止、再生がうまくいきません。

Tags: javascript

JSでsetTimeoutでのスライドショーの停止、再生がうまくいきません。

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVNgLr

```js
let iterative = () => {
  setTimeout(myChange, 5000); // 
}

const pauseBtn = document.getElementById('js-pause-btn');
pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearTimeout(iterative);
});

const playBtn = document.getElementById('js-play-btn');
playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  iterative();
});
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-wrap-selectimg--slidegame">
  <div class="slideshow-wrap-selectimg--slidegame__slideimg-wrap">
    <img id="idshow1-selectimg--slidegame" class="slideshow-wrap__item1-selectimg--slidegame is-fadeout-selectimg--slidegame" src="img/common-img/corpolate-img.jpg">
    <img id="idshow2-selectimg--slidegame" class="slideshow-wrap__item2-selectimg--slidegame is-fadein--slidegame" src="img/common-img/corpolate-img.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-wrap-selectimg--slidegame__selectimg-wrap">
    <ul>
      <li id="js-selectimg-list1--slidegame" class="slideshow-wrap-selectimg--slidegame__select-list">
        <img class="slideshow-wrap-selectimg--slidegame__item1" src="img/common-img/corpolate-img.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li id="js-selectimg-list2--slidegame" class="slideshow-wrap-selectimg--slidegame__select-list">
        <img class="slideshow-wrap-selectimg--slidegame__item2" src="img/common-img/corpolate-img.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li id="js-selectimg-list3--slidegame" class="slideshow-wrap-selectimg--slidegame__select-list">
        <img class="slideshow-wrap-selectimg--slidegame__item3" src="img/common-img/corpolate-img.jpg" alt="">
      </li>
      <li>
        <!-- href="javascript:void(0)"-リンク先に飛ばないようにする。 -->
        <a id="js-pause-btn" class="controle-btn-wrap__link p-ripple-effect--most-top" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="c-controle-btn-wrap__item--slidegame material-icons u-text-shadow-0dot1rem-0dot1rem-0dot1rem-a0dot4">pause</i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="js-play-btn" class="controle-btn-wrap__link p-ripple-effect--most-top" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="c-controle-btn-wrap__item--slidegame material-icons u-text-shadow-0dot1rem-0dot1rem-0dot1rem-a0dot4">play_arrow</i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

問題なく動いているので、停止再生の部分以外は間違えがないと思うのですが、
停止再生の部分に問題はありますでしょうか？
抜粋しておきました。

```
let iterative = ()=> {
    setTimeout(myChange , 5000);                    // 
}

const pauseBtn = document.getElementById('js-pause-btn');
pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    clearTimeout(iterative);
});

const playBtn = document.getElementById('js-play-btn');
playBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    iterative();
});
```

Comment: `let iterative = ()=> {
    setTimeout(myChange , 5000);                    // 
}` は、`let iterative = function() { setTimeout(myChange , 5000); };` （関数オブジェクトと実質同じ）ですので、「変数intertiveに入った」のは中身の関数の返値ではなく `setTimeout`をラップしている関数です。

Comment: 実際に試してはいませんが、おそらく`iterative` は、関数として実行されることを期待されているので単なる値として書き換えると動作しないと思います。なので、その解決策（？）はよろしくないです。

Comment: そうです。iterativeは関数として再生の時に再実行することと、停止の時に停止できることを期待しています。

Comment: _iterative = setTimeout(myChange, 5000); と代入、変数に入れると関数が単なる値になってしまうのですか？

Comment: let iterative = ()=> {
    if(TimeID == null)
        TimeID = setInterval(myChange , 500); 
}を参考にしたのですがこれが完全方法なんではないのですか？なぜifを使う必要があるのかよくわかりませんが上記のソースだとどのようにすればよいか教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: 「代入、変数に入れると関数が単なる値になってしまうのですか？」関数の返値で書き換えているからです。変数の中身が関数だったのが値で置き換えられてしまいます。

Comment: ２番目例のようにすればいいかと思います。

Comment: 停まる、停まらない（あるいは「どうすればよいか」）の話はsetTimeout,clearTimeoutの使用法以前にスライドショーのAPIの話であるような気がしますが、開始・停止はこのようにしなさいというマニュアル的なものはどうなってますか？

Comment: let iterative =  {
    setTimeout(myChange , 5000);                    // 
}
とした場合ちゃんと止まっていますのでスライドショーに問題はないです

Comment: ならばそういうことでいいです。お疲れ様。

Comment: すでに記載していますが停止は上記でできるがこれですと名前のある関数にできないので再度動かすことができないのです。

Comment: var playBtn = document.getElementById('js-play-btn');
        playBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            _iterative();
        });
が変数に代入しただけではできないですよね

Comment: マルチポスト先で質問を継続する事にしたようです。
https://okwave.jp/qa/q9320398.html

Comment: ここで解決しないので仕方がなかったのです随分と待ったけど解決しないなら他の意見も求めて仕方がないと思います

Comment: To: @temestack さん、@BLUEPIXY さんがコード付きの回答に修正されてからあなたが無視しているように見えましたが、暗黙の内に解決しないから無視されていたようですね。
マルチポストに関しては、「質問者側の事情だけ」を考慮すれば有意義な方法ですが、回答者に負担がかかる為、一般的にはマナー違反とされています。
「[マルチポスト - Wikipedia(Link)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88)]」に「マナー違反の理由」「失礼にならない方法」が説明されていますので、お読みになる事を推奨します。「[他の質問でも多数マルチポストされている(Link)](https://www.google.co.jp/search?num=30&q=site%3Aokwave.jp+inurl%3A%2Fqa%2F+intitle%3Ajavascript+htmlcss123)」ようですが、OKWaveとstackoverflowの両方にマルチポスト先URLを書いておくのが望ましいと私は思います。

Comment: 質問を編集し、整理しました。念のため申し上げておきますが、JavaScript の基礎について質問なさるのはまったく構いません。
ただ、応用的内容やAPIの使用方法などの質問で、それらの基礎・前提となる部分まで質問が及び、芋蔓式に説明が必要になると、StackOverflowの単独の「Q&A」で扱える内容ではなくなります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)の返値が保存されていません。
その値をペアとなる[clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout)に引数として渡す必要があります。

---

サンプルコード
実際の`myChange`の内容（スライドショーを開始する？）などは私にはわからない（スライドショーの停止としてので、clearTimeoutを使うのが適切であるかどうかなどもわからない）ので
この実行動作は単なるサンプルとして適当に作ってます。
（またsetTimeout,clearTimeoutの代わりにsetInterval,clearIntervalを使用しています。このサンプルのためにきっかけだけでなく連続動作をになうため）
PLAYボタンを押すとテキストエリアに`*`を追加表示し続けます。
PAUSEボタンを押すと停止します。
PLAYボタンを押すと再開します。
複数回同じボタンが連続して押される場合のために、
PLAYボタンを押したらPLAYボタンがDISABLEされて押せなくなるなどの排他処理が必要です。
以下の場合はTimeIDが既に設定されているか（nullでないか）どうかで処理を分けています。

```js
let myChange = ()=> {
  document.getElementById('disp').value += "*";
}

let TimeID = null;

let iterative = ()=> {
    if(TimeID == null)
        TimeID = setInterval(myChange , 500); 
}

const pauseBtn = document.getElementById('js-pause-btn');
pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    if(TimeID != null){
        clearInterval(TimeID);
        TimeID = null;
    }
});

const playBtn = document.getElementById('js-play-btn');
playBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    iterative();
});
```

```html
<textarea cols="20" rows=10" id="disp"></textarea><br />
<button type="button" id="js-play-btn">PLAY</button>
<button type="button" id="js-pause-btn">PAUSE</button<br />
```

---

setTimeout, clearTimeoutを使用する例（ボタンを使用不可にする）

```js
let myChange = ()=> {
    document.getElementById('disp').value += "*";
    iterative();//これがあるはず。
}

let TimeID = null;

let iterative = ()=> {
    TimeID = setTimeout(myChange , 500); 
}

const pauseBtn = document.getElementById('js-pause-btn');
pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    clearTimeout(TimeID);
    playBtn.disabled = false;
});

const playBtn = document.getElementById('js-play-btn');
playBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    playBtn.disabled = true;
    iterative();
});
```

```html
<textarea cols="20" rows=10" id="disp"></textarea><br />
<button type="button" id="js-play-btn">PLAY</button>
<button type="button" id="js-pause-btn">PAUSE</button<br />
```

Comment: もしかしてreturnで渡すのですか？
上記のように変数に全体を入れてその変数を引数に指定すればよいと思っていたのですが

Comment: @temestack  `iterative`自体はラップする関数になります。

Comment: babelを使っているので名前のある関数にするにはlet iterative = ()=> {とするしかなくこのようにしていました。
ただ変数にも入れたいし名前のある関数にもしたいしbabelも使いたい場合どのようにすれば良いのでしょか？

Comment: setTimeout(myChange , 5000);をfunctionで囲むとなぜclearできないのでしょうか？

Comment: @temestack  `iterative();` で関数`iterative`が呼び出されるとその中身である`setTimeout`関数が呼び出されてその返された値は使われずに捨てられるからですね。`clearTimeout`には関数`iterative`が渡されていて`setTimeout`関数が返した値では無いから止まらないというわけですね。既に説明した通りです。

Comment: @temestack 使用サンプルを追加しました。setIntervalとclearIntervalを使用していますが要するにセット側の返した値をペアとなる停止側で使うという点で同じです。特に特別なことはしていないのでbabelが使えないということはないはずと思います。